# If $\phi: X \to Y$ is a dominant morphism of varieties, then for some $V$ open in $Y$, the restriction to $\phi^{-1}(V)$ is universally open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We're give $\phi : X \to Y$ is a dominant morphism of irreducible varieties, then asked to show there exists a non-empty open set $V$ of $Y$ such that $\phi:\phi^{-1}(V) \to V$ is universally open, that is $$\phi \times id_{Z}:\phi^{-1}(V) \times Z \to V \times Z$$ is an open map for any variety $Z$.

I would like to know how to go about proving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generic flatness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_flatness) give the answer: in your situation, there exists a nonempty open set $V\subset Y$ such that $\mathcal{O}_X$ restricted to $\phi^{-1}(V)$ is flat over $V$. Since flat morphisms which are locally of finite presentation are universally open, we have what you want.